# "sudo su -" vs "sudo su" command

Tags: sudo

I have RHEL (virtual box) server that I need to install puppet modules from a puppet master. I was told to log in as root then run puppet agent command. So I ran following command.

```
sudo su
puppet agent -t
```

Execution went fine without an error. Let's say file "A" was pushed down from the master to the target server but I noticed that file size of "A" did not match between the master and the target server. I thought that was odd....I removed the file "A" from the target server then logged out and logged back in as root BUT with hypen "-" this time then ran puppet agent command.

```
sudo su -
puppet agent -t
```

Execution went fine without an error BUT this time the file size of "A" matched. I am curious to know why.

Comment: It's the same commands as the duplicate Q, but the other Answer doesn't explain why puppet behaves differently. DaeYoung, you'll want to look at the environment variables that get set during a 'sudo su -'; one of those is likely influencing puppet's behavior.

Comment: I see...Thank you @Jeff Schaller. I will definitely look into it.